# Java 2D Array return not correct, why?

Tags: java, if-statement, multidimensional-array, return, iteration

Why I get `-1` returned? For sure the name is in `stadiumSeats[i][j]`.

```
`public int searchForGuest(final String name){       
    for(int i=0; i<stadiumSeats.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<stadiumSeats.length; j++){
            if(stadiumSeats[i][j] == name){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare string ，use function equal